# Highcharts DateTime not parsing correctly

Tags: highcharts

I'm using UTC epoch strings, but they are not imported correctly.  None of the other datetime issues I've looked at on stackOverflow are helping.  See this screenshot:  https://www.screencast.com/t/Y7NWA09BKHY

And man, is this chart ugly :/  Any style hints for a bootstrap layout would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Use milliseconds, not seconds, from 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC.